# How doesn't duplicate records to ormlite

Tags: java, android, ormlite

I have a one problem. My app connects with WebService and downloads data about breweries. These data are saved to OrmliteDB.

What should I do so that database doesn't duplicate records which are the same.

**window.java**

```
dbHelper = (DatabaseHelper) OpenHelperManager.getHelper(getApplication(), DatabaseHelper.class);

final RuntimeExceptionDao studDao = dbHelper.getStudRuntimeExceptionDao();
BeerDataBaseTemplate wdt = new BeerDataBaseTemplate();

for (Datum i : breweries.getData()) {
    if (i.getName() != null && i.getAbv() != null && i.getDescription() != null && i.getLabels() != null) {
          studDao.createIfNotExists(new BeerDataBaseTemplate("" + i.getName(), i.getAbv(), i.getDescription(), i.getLabels().getMedium().toString(), i.getLabels().getLarge().toString(), false));
    } else if (i.getName() != null && i.getAbv() != null && i.getDescription() == null && i.getLabels() != null) {
         studDao.createOrUpdate(new BeerDataBaseTemplate("" + i.getName(), i.getAbv(), "Brak danych", i.getLabels().getMedium().toString(), i.getLabels().getLarge().toString(), false));
    } else if (i.getName() != null && i.getAbv() != null && i.getDescription() == null && i.getLabels() == null) {
         studDao.createOrUpdate(new BeerDataBaseTemplate("" + i.getName(), i.getAbv(), "Brak danych", "Brak zdjęcia", "Brak zdjęcia", false));
     } else if (i.getName() != null && i.getAbv() == null && i.getDescription() == null && i.getLabels() == null) {
         studDao.createOrUpdate(new BeerDataBaseTemplate("" + i.getName(), "Brak danych", "Brak danych", "Brak zdjęcia", "Brak zdjęcia", false));
    } else if (i.getName() == null && i.getAbv() == null && i.getDescription() == null && i.getLabels() == null) {
        studDao.createOrUpdate(new BeerDataBaseTemplate("Brak danych", "Brak danych", "Brak danych", "Brak zdjęcia", "Brak zdjęcia", false));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you go do is to get all of the ids of the incoming records into a `Collection` and then do something like:

```
GenericRawResults<String[]> results
    = studDao.queryRaw("SELECT id FROM stud WHERE id IN ?", newIdCollection);
```

Then you would know which ids are new and which were duplicates.  Then you could update (or ignore) the dups and create the new ones whose ids don't already exist in your table.

Be sure to do the mass updates and creates as a batch operation which will run a lot faster.